# Unable to fire pageview in Prestashop for Google Analytics

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I installed Google Analytics pugin v2.3 in this PrestaShop site.

https://www.sonosif.com

But Analytics is not tracking any sessions. I already setup the account in admin. 
Google Tag Assistant says that it find the GA account, but nothing is fired.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because plugin is missing

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

in it's javascript snippet.

Javascript snippet is in [modules/ganalytics/ganalytics.php](https://github.com/PrestaShop/ganalytics/blob/master/ganalytics.php#L265)

You can add the command there, though you'd probably want to override module to prevent it being erased if module gets updated.